# How should I proceed when I get the "Unable to Purchase" alert from the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Recently, whenever I want to buy something from the iOS App Store or update my existing apps, I get the usual password dialog, but after a second that disappears and I see the following alert:

[image]

After clicking `OK` and then entering my password the app installs just fine (and gets billed correctly).

Strangely sometimes the apps mentioned in the `Unable to Purchase` alert get marked as `Waiting...` on the homescreen, even though there are no updates for them.

When this happens I am unable to start those apps, until later, when it magically disappears again.

This happens on both an iPhone 4S and an iPad 2, running iOS 5.1.

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken and do you use Installous?

Comment: Nope, all devices are 'legit', one is in Developer mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a previous discussion on [the Apple Discussion boards](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2484914?start=0&tstart=0), you should sign out and sign in again in your Store settings.

And if that doesn't work, their is always [another fix](http://www.blog.gleff.com/2012/03/app-store-unable-to-purchase-fix/), which involves downloading a 3th party software. No jailbreak required!

Comment: Going to Settings -> Store and logging out and in again fixed the issue on the iPad 2. So I think this will work on all devices, testing on the new iPad next, but consider this closed. Thanks!

Comment: Just a late follow-up: I tried the sign out and in again twice on my 4S, and it doesn't work there. Strangely it fixes the issue on the iPads. Anyway, here's hope for a bugfix update in the future..